# SSIS Package Putting out too Many Columns

Tags: csv, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am using DataLoader For SalesForce which is reading in a flat file created from an SSIS package. However, there are a few rows that are putting out too many columns. I don't understand how a simple query could put out extra columns once in a while. Does anyone understand how a csv file could all of a sudden begin shooting out an extra column? Here is the query (with 20 columns(CSV)).

```
SELECT
dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.CUSTACCOUNT AS 'Account_Number__c',
dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT AS 'Business_Relation_Number__c',
DIMENSION2_ AS 'Division__c',
QUOTATIONEXPIRYDATE AS 'Expiration__c',
PMF_NOOFITEMS AS 'Number_of_Items__c',
CREATEDDATE AS 'Quote_Date__c',
QUOTATIONID AS 'Quote_Number_Ext_ID__c',
QUOTATIONID AS 'Name',
PAYMENT AS 'Terms__c',
SALESGROUP AS 'Territory__c',
dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT AS 'Account_CBusiness_Relation_Number__c',
CASE dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.QUOTATIONSTATUS
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Created'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Sent'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Confirmed'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Lost'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Cancelled'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Won'
    ELSE 'Unknown' END AS 'Quote_Status__c',
'"' + REPLACE(NAME, '"', '') + '"' AS 'Contact_Name__c',
PHONE AS 'Contact_Phone__c',
dbo.CONTACTPERSON.EMAIL AS 'Contact_Email__c',
PMF_RFQRECEIVEDDATE AS 'Quote_Recieved_Date__c',
PMF_QUOTESENTDATE AS 'Quote_Sent_Date__c',
PGMNAME AS 'Program_Name__c',
OEM AS 'OEM_c',
(SELECT TOP 1(NAME) from USERINFO where SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.SalesTaker = USERINFO.NETWORKALIAS) as 'Pricing_Specialist_c'        
FROM
    dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.CONTACTPERSON ON dbo.SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.CONTACTPERSONID = dbo.CONTACTPERSON.CONTACTPERSONID
WHERE
    CREATEDDATE >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 30, 101)
    OR
    --Only update quotes that were created in 2013 or after
    (MODIFIEDDATE >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 30, 101)
    AND
    YEAR(CREATEDDATE) > 2012)
```

Here's the Flat File:
[image: Flat File]

As you can see from the below preveiw picture there are extra commas inside the box
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're outputting a csv.  Are you sure your data fields have no commas in them?  That can manifest as "extra" columns when you read the csv file.  Or does your "NAME" field have single-quotes and commas in it that might break your explicit double-quoting?

Look at the records with "extra" fields in them & trace back to your source data.  The first spurious value will tell you where the breakage is.

Comment: There appears to be an extra column before Pricing_specialist_c once n a while. It will insert an extra comma. The field before is comma separated but that field has A CRLF.
Still not sure why it doesn't do it every time.

Comment: What does your source data look like for those lines compared to lines that don't have the 'extra' fields?

Answer (score 0):

The Flat File Connection Manager preview is showing the comma as part of the Pricing_Specialist_c column, which it wouldn't do if it thought the comma were indicating an additional column.  It looks like the previewer is accepting that the comma is INSIDE whatever text qualifier is being used.

If you look at the csv file in Notepad, I'm guessing you will see lines ending somewhat like this:

```
..., 5360, 5363, ",Angela Young"
```

I haven't used "DataLoader For SalesForce", but if it's adding a separate column after the double-quoted comma, it's presumably ignoring the text qualifier.  You could work with this tool to get it to recognize the current text qualifier.  Or you could have SSIS use a different text qualifier that is better recognized by DataLoader For SalesForce.  Or, finally, you could figure out why your USERINFO.NAME column data seems to contain spurious commas, and try removing them.